# Unable to use positional arguments in parallel scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a bunch of scripts pass on 3 positional arguments in to another script.  When I run it serially it works fine.

**ripper.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -e

set -x

# Sock Puppets!!!


./automate_tests.sh quorum t2.xlarge us-east-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum t2.2xlarge us-east-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum t3.2xlarge us-east-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum t3a.xlarge us-west-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum t3a.2xlarge us-west-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum a1.4xlarge  us-west-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum a1.metal ca-central-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m4.xlarge ca-central-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m4.2xlarge  ca-central-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m4.4xlarge eu-central-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m4.10xlarge eu-north-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m4.16xlarge eu-north-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.2xlarge eu-north-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.4xlarge eu-north-1 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.8xlarge eu-west-3 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.12xlarge eu-west-3 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.16xlarge  eu-west-3 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.24xlarge eu-west-3 
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.metal eu-west-1
```

**automate_tests.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -e

set -x

CLIENT=$1
VM_FAMILY=$2 
REGION=$3
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run `ripper.sh` as a parallel job using `nohup sh ripper.sh > out &` and edit as shown below, it doesn't pass the positional arguments to `automate_tests.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash -e

set -x

# Sock Puppets!!!


./automate_tests.sh quorum t2.xlarge us-east-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum t2.2xlarge us-east-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum t3.2xlarge us-east-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum t3a.xlarge us-west-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum t3a.2xlarge us-west-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum a1.4xlarge  us-west-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum a1.metal ca-central-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m4.xlarge ca-central-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m4.2xlarge  ca-central-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m4.4xlarge eu-central-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m4.10xlarge eu-north-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m4.16xlarge eu-north-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.2xlarge eu-north-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.4xlarge eu-north-1 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.8xlarge eu-west-3 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.12xlarge eu-west-3 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.16xlarge  eu-west-3 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.24xlarge eu-west-3 &
./automate_tests.sh quorum m5.metal eu-west-1 &
wait
```

**Output**

```
 + CLIENT=
 + VM_FAMILY=
 + REGION=
```

The variables are blank. I would appreciate any pointers on how I can get this to work.

### Update

I have found that when I run the the script without `nohup` it works. I need to be able to run these process for more than 6 hours and therefore need a way to get this to work. Would love pointers

Comment: Can you please confirm that you can reproduce the issue when you copy-paste the scripts from your post into a new directory (without reusing your existing files)?

Comment: Adding `&` won't make `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` suddenly become empty. There's something else going on that is missing from your question.

Comment: it will help if you redirect both - `stdin` and `stderr` to file so hopefully you see any errors

Comment: @akostadinov thanks already doing that . `ripper.sh > out.txt`

Comment: @JohnKugelman I think I might have found the culprit. The script works with `nohup` i.e. if i run `./ripper.sh` it passes the variables to 'automate_test.sh`. Do you know what I can do about this as I need it to run for a very long time (i.e 6 hours)

Comment: @SamuelDare `ripper.sh > out.txt` only redirects standard output; to redirect standard error as well, use `ripper.sh > out.txt 2>&1`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I cant seem to get the redirection to work. Here is the output `nohup bash automate_tests.sh > out.txt 2&1 
[2] 22987
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
1: command not found`

Comment: You used `2&1`. You have to use `2>&1`

Comment: Also, I agree with John Kugelman -- there's something else going on that isn't in your question. I recommend making copies of the scripts, then simplifying them as much as possible. For example, remove the multiple runs of automate_tests.sh and see if the problem is still there. Remove everything except the problem sections from both scripts and test again. Then remove the `&` from ripper.sh and test again. Remove as many complications as possible without fixing the problem. Then, post that trimmed-down version of the problem scripts.

Comment: @GordonDavisson are you it has nothing to do with `nohup` ? it works fine without it

Comment: `nohup` may be part of it, but it's not the whole story. BTW, the parallel version works as expected for me, both with & without `nohup`. So *something* else is going on.

Comment: Weird problem, but since you've apparently isolated it to `nohup`: 1. `nohup --version`? 2. Use GNU `parallel` instead of bg, `nohup`, and `wait`, e.g., `grep '^\./automate_tests.sh' ripper.sh | parallel`